# Error when displaying the elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int path[10]={'_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'};
for (int b=0;b<=9;b++) {
     cout << path[b];
}
```

When I try to run this to display a horizontal line it just shows a lot of 9s and 5s. But however if I run this one

```
for (int b=0;b<=9;b++) {
     cout << '_';
}
```

It seems to do the work. I know I can just use the 2nd bulk of code but I need to display it using the array.

Comment: Distinguish `char` and `int`.

Comment: Oh my. Such a terrible mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`path` is an array of `int`, when you print out its elements the `int` value (i.e. the ascii code `95` for `'_'`) will be printed out. If you want it to be printed out as `char`, you should change the declaration from

```
int path[10]={'_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'};
```

to

```
char path[10]={'_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'};
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you declare `path` as an array of `int` and it gets interpreted by `std::cout` like an int (ASCII code for `_` is 95). To make it work, you need to change the declaration to:

```
int path[10]={'_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'};
```

In the second example you output `'_'` to `std::cout`, which is a `char` type and is displayed as you expected.